# How to integrate $\int{xe^{x}\sin{x}}~dx$

Tags: integration

How to integrate

$$\int{xe^{x}\sin{x}}~dx$$

I tried taking $v=xe^{x}$ and using integration by parts, but that became lengthy and didn't work.

Comment: Integration by part is the right method. Check carefully your steps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: Use integration by parts, where $x = u$ and $y = e^x \sin(x)$.

Hint 2: The first hint may not be helpful, especially if you haven't already encountered the integral of $e^x \sin(x)$. Finding an antiderivative of that is a  nontrivial sub-problem that involves using integration by parts twice and solving an equation for the variable $\int e^x \sin(x) \, \textrm{d}x$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$x\mathrm e^x\sin x=\operatorname{Im}x\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}$, hence
$$\int x\mathrm e^x\sin x\,\mathrm dx=\operatorname{Im}\biggl(\int x\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}\,\mathrm dx\biggr).$$